# How to create a fluent Aggregation using MongoDB C# Driver 2.0

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm quite new to MongoDB and I'm using it in a Web Api to serve a mobile application.

Now, I need to run an aggregation and since I'm using C#, I would like to do it fluently by using the `Aggregate` command on a collection which returns me an `IAggregateFluent`.

However, I'm stuck and the information which I found here on SO doesn't help me, so therefore a new question.

I've built a small collection that holds smartphones with some basic properties, and a single item in the smartphone collection does look like:

```
{
    "name" : "LG Nexus 5",
    "description" : "A Nexus 5 device, created by Google.",
    "typenr" : "LG-NEX-5/WHITE",
    "props" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "os",
            "value" : "Android"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "storage",
            "value" : "8"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "storage",
            "value" : "16"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "storage",
            "value" : "32"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "storage",
            "value" : "64"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I've created an aggregation in the shell which looks like the following:

```
// Get all the amount of filters that are defined.
db.smartphones.aggregate([
    // Unwind the "props".
    { "$unwind" : "$props" },

    // Grouping phase.
    // Group by unique properties, add a count for the amount of articles, and add articles to an element named "articles".
    // We use the function "$addToSet" here to ensure that only unique articles are being added.
    { 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$props", 
            count : { "$sum" : 1 }, 
            articles: { 
                "$addToSet": { 
                    name: "$name", 
                    description: "$description", 
                    typenr: "$typenr" 
                } x =>
            } 
        } 
    },

    // Sort the results based on the "_id" field.
    { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 } }
]);
```

And now I need to translate this to C#.

First, I do create the following (plain C# code, it just returns an `IMongoCollection<Article>`).

```
var collection = context.ArticleRepository;
```

Here's the model which the collection does return:

```
public class Article
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Unique identifier for the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Name of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("name")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Name of the element but in lowercase.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     We'll create this field to enable text-search on this field without respecting capital letters.
    /// </remarks>
    [BsonElement("namelc")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString LowercaseName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Specification of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("specification")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Specificiation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Brand of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("brand")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Brand { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Supplier of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("supplier")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Number of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("nr")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString ArticleNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gtin number of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("gtin")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string ArticleGtin { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     type number of the article.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("typeNr")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string TypeNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Properties of the article.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This field can be used to ensure that we can filter on the articles.
    ///     By default, this is an empty list, this avoids initialization logic.
    /// </remarks>
    [BsonElement("props")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public List<ArticleProperty> Properties { get; set; } = new List<ArticleProperty>();

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
///     Class representing a single supplier in the database.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     This class is not used as a "root" document inside our database.
///     Instead, it's being embedded into our "Articles" document.
/// </remarks>
public class Supplier
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Name of the supplier.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("supplier")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gln of the supplier.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("gln")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Gln { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
///     Class representing a single property for an article in the database.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     This class is not used as a "root" document inside our database.
///     Instead, it's being embedded into our "Articles" document.
/// </remarks>
public class ArticleProperty
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Type of the property.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("type")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Value of the property.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement("value")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public BsonString Value { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, I need to aggregate on this collection, and I'm strugling already with the basics:

```
// Build the aggregation using the fluent api.
var aggregation = collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(x => x.Properties)
    .Group(x => new { x.Properties );
```

Right now, I only try to group on properties, like in the aggregation but this results in the following error:

`CS0411 The type arguments for method 'IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument>.Group<TNewResult>(ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument, TNewResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

But even when that's working, I also need the extra properties as `count` and `addToSet`. Can someone help me with this one.
I'm already searching for 2 days on this and it's driving me crazy.

**Edit**

I've found that a group followed by an unwind does work in C#, but why doesn't it work with the unwind first? I really need the unwind to happen first.

**Edit 2**
I've managed to get a small portion working, inclusive the `group` command. See the code below:

```
var aggregation = collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<Smartphone, UnwindedSmartphone>(x => x.Properties)
    .Group(key => key.Property, g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    });
```

However, I need some more information on how to push the Articles property from the aggregation command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem.
The following C# code should be used:

```
var aggregation = collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<Smartphone, UnwindedSmartphone>(x => x.Properties)
    .Group(key => key.Property, g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        Articles = g.Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Name
        }).Distinct()
    })
    .SortBy(x => x.Id);
```

This gives me the following aggregation:

```
db.smartphones.aggregate([{ "$unwind" : "$props" }, { "$group" : { "_id" :     "$props", "Count" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "Articles" : { "$addToSet" : { "Name" :     "$name" } } } }, { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 } }])
```